# How to show time of day (7:42 AM) in VLC fullscreen mode?

Tags: vlc-media-player, time, fullscreen

Is there a way to show the time of day in the corner somewhere which in VLC fullscreen mode?

Comment: Probably not inherently to VLC... But which OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8. Any hacks?

Comment: This answer tells how to do this: https://superuser.com/a/723564/707985