# How to add system time to VLC toolbar?

Tags: vlc-media-player, fullscreen

I am using VLC Media Player to run video and audio file. I want to know whether it's possible to add the current system time to the toolbar of VLC Player. It would be easier to check the system time without escaping from the full screen mode.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how to add time details in tool bar of vlc media player. But we can add time and date as a marquee. There are two ways to do this one is using command line and the other by manually changing the settings

**1. Command line**

```
vlc.exe --sub-filter=marq{marquee=$T/$D" Volume:"$V,size=-2,color=16776960}:marq{marquee=Time:%H:%M:%S" Date:"%d/%m/%Y,color=16776960,size=-2,position=6}
```

Open CMD (command prompt) and then go to the directory in which vlc is installed and enter the above code

**2. Manual**

*VLC 2.1.2

- Go to ***Tools > Preference***
- Change ***Show settings*** from ***Simple*** to ***All***
- Uncheck the  ***only show current*** option
- Type in the search box ***marquee***
- Select ***Subtitles/OSD*** from the list
- Check the box ***marquee display*** found in overlays
- Select from the list ;subsection ***Marquee*** which is in ***Subtitles/OSD***
- In the ***Text*** box type ***Time:%H:%M:%S*** for time and ***Date:"%d/%m/%Y*** for current date
- Tweak the marquee properites in ***marquee display*** according to your convinence
- Save the preference and then run a new video